# Display public user's facebook posts on website

Tags: javascript, php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I want to display one particular user's wall on the person's website. If I use the Graph API: `https://graph.facebook.com/{id}/posts?limit=8&access_token={token}`, it works for about 2 hours until the access token expires. What kind of solution would make it permanent? I understand that I need to use an app to achieve this, but can't find out how. A solution using either PHP or JavaScript is would be the best.

All suggestions are welcome!

Answer (score 0):

You can extend a User Token to 60 days (more about that [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens/) and [here](http://www.devils-heaven.com/facebook-access-tokens/), for example).

After that, you would need to refresh the Token, and you have to do that manually. User Profiles are not meant to be used for that, and you will not get `read_stream` approved in order to make it available for anyone who is NOT an Admin/Developer/Tester of your app. So this would be something only you can use.

You can show the feed of a Facebok Page though, there is an [Extended Page Token](http://www.devils-heaven.com/extended-page-access-tokens-curl/) that is valid forever. There is no User Token that is valid forever.

Comment: I have the same situation as above, the user is a motivational speaker and we want to use her FB public posts in a similar manner as Twitter feed. Can she renew the token somehow herself?

Comment: of course, you just have to create a page with facebook login where she can renew the token by just visiting it when the token is not valid anymore. take a look at FB.getLoginStatus for refreshing a token. you need to store the new one then. that is, if you are talking about a user token. extended page tokens are valid forever anyway.

Comment: no, it's not a "page", she is just starting out and we want to use her personal FB profile for marketing. When she gets to be a female Tony Robbins, we will create a page for her. I am amazed on how little info is available on creating and using FB public user feed and about ready to hire somebody to program that for me!

Comment: you are not allowed to use user profiles for commerical reasons, btw. either way, it´s fairly easy to post stuff to a user profile with the api - but then again, i am using the api since a lot of years...